# Rails4 jquery.countdownでカウントダウン終了時刻がずれる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

Rails4.16でgemのjquery.countdownを使っています。
カウントダウンの終了時刻が期待した動きになりません

例 
現在時刻 5月7日0時35分
設定時刻(@item.limit_time)を5月7日16時に設定 →　カウントダウンは0時0分0秒

現在時刻 5月7日0時35分
設定時刻(@item.limit_time)を5月8日16時に設定 →　カウントダウンは23時23分0秒

pry(main)でupdate時刻をコンソールで確認したところ、
更新しているにもかかわらずupdated_at: "2015-05-06 15:35:50"（現在は2015-05-07 00:48:49 +0900）となっているのがおかしいとわかるのですが、
active_admin上では 2015-05-07 00:48:49 +0900なのです。

> class Application < Rails::Application
>   　　　config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
>      　　　config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

```
#javascript

$ ->
  $('.countdown').each ->
    $(this).countdown
      until: new Date($(this).data('until'))
      format: $(this).data('format')
    return
  return


#view

<div class="countdown" data-until= <%= @item.limit_time %> ></div>
#limit_timeカラムはdatetimeです。
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もしかしたら打ち間違いかもしれませんが、クォーテーションの付け忘れということは無いですか？TimeWithZone#to_s は、`2015-05-07 00:48:49 +0900` のように日付と時刻の間にスペースが入ってますので、以下のようにクォーテーションでくくらないと、時刻以下が`date-until` として認識されないかと思います。

```
<div class="countdown" data-until="<%= @item.limit_time %>" ></div>
```

時刻が認識されていない（00:00:00と計算されている）と仮定すると、一応、カウントダウンの計算結果は合ってますね。

Comment: ご指摘の通りでした。ありがとうございます。
<div class="countdown" data-until= "<%= @item.limit_day %>" ></div>
としたところすべて正しく動作しました。

Answer (score 0):

詳細はよくわかりませんが、タイムゾーンがうまくかみ合っていないようですね。HTMLとして出力されているdata-untilの値は何になっていますか？

また、countdown.jsではuntilにtimezoneを渡すオプションもあるようなので、これを使ってタイムゾーンがかみ合うよう調整してみてはいかがでしょうか？

http://keith-wood.name/countdownref.html#timezone

Comment: <div class="countdown" data-until= 2015/05/07 16:55 ></div>でした。
原因はクォーテーションが付いていないためでした。
ありがとうございました。